# How to properly calculate annual irradiance using QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, grass-7.0, solar-radiation

I want to calculate annual irradiance for a couple of buildings to establish how much PV energy can be potentially harvested.

Which algorithm You recommend for this purpose: **"r.sun"** from GRASS toolbox, or SAGA **"Potential Incoming Solar Radiation"** ?

Can You recommend any tutorial that explains step by step what inputs are required (i.e. not only DEM/DSM but also any atmospheric factors), what settings (or formulas) should be applied to obtain accurate results?

I am aware that this subject (or its elements) might be already discussed, but since I am a newbie, I am looking for comprehensive, holistic explanation what approach I should follow.

Comment: GRASS r.sun and SAGA module deal with solar resource only. But if the aim is PV energy potential, maybe it is good idea to use some PV simulation tools (yes, solar radiation is the most important but not the only paramter). There are some free apps on the web, e.g. https://globalsolaratlas.info/, and definitely some more sophisticated commercial apps.